# NHibernate Criterion Problem

Tags: nhibernate

I have a query in hibernate that looks like:

```
string[] NewsId = new string[] {"ABC","DEF","GHI"};

public IEnumerable<News> NewsSelected(string[] NewsId)
    {

        List<ICriterion> criteria = new List<ICriterion>();
        criteria.Add(Restrictions.In("Id", NewsId));
        var results = _repository.GetByCriteria(criteria);
        return results;
    }
```

It returns zero, but

```
public IEnumerable<News> NewsSelected(string[] NewsId)
    {

        List<ICriterion> criteria = new List<ICriterion>();
        criteria.Add(Restrictions.In("Id", new[]{"ABC","DEF","GHI"}));
        var results = _repository.GetByCriteria(criteria);
        return results;
    }
```

works perfectly. What am I missing here?

Comment: In the first snippet, who calls `NewsSelected` and with what arguments? Is the definition above the function supposed to be a static array declaration? In the second snippet, why do you have a `NewsId` parameter if it's not used anywhere?

Comment: So in the debugger in the first instance NewsId contains exactly the same data as in the second snippet? There's got to be something wrong with the way you're calling the first function.

Answer (score 0):

You need copy query parameters to a local variable like that:

```
string[] NewsId = new string[] {"ABC","DEF","GHI"};

public IEnumerable<News> NewsSelected(string[] NewsId)
{
    var newsId = NewsId;

    List<ICriterion> criteria = new List<ICriterion>();
    criteria.Add(Restrictions.In("Id", newsId));
    var results = _repository.GetByCriteria(criteria);
    return results;
}
```